# Rearranging values of a matrix using np.argsort

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

For this code, I am truncating an infinite (nxn) matrix so that I can solve using a 14x14 matrix. I want the eigenvalues to be listed in numerical order, from lowest to highest.

Code before using np.argsort:

```
h = np.loadtxt("g14")
eig, v = LA.eig(h)
print("The eigenvalues for this anharmonic oscillator are", eig)
```

To which the terminal prints out

```
The eigenvalues...are
[3.63...e+02  1.56...e+02  6.42...e+01  4.32...e+02
...etc ]
```

Code with np.argsort:

```
h = np.loadtxt("g14")
eig, v = LA.eig(h)
e = np.argsort(eig)
print("The eigenvalues for this anharmonic oscillator are", e)
```

To which the terminal prints out

```
The eigenvalues...are
[8 12  9 13  7 11  5 10  2  6  1  4  0  3]
```

This is obviously not a rearrangement of the eigenvalue matrix spewed out by LA.eig(h).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[numpy.argsort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) returns the positions (index) that each element would be placed in the sorted array.  If you are looking to return the sorted output eigenvalues,
 you can simply use [numpy.sort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html).